# Problemas con Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicación del juego de la ruleta, donde para apostar el jugador deberá presionar botones.

No logro hacer que se compute el numero de apuestas realizadas en un JLabel.

Lo que debe devolver el JLabel es el `contador` + `(JLabelname.getText())-->INT`

Aquí dejo la clase:

```
public class Chip extends JButton implements MouseListener {
    public int contador=0;

    int suma=0;
    public String ap;
    public JLabel apuesta=new JLabel();

    public Chip(JLabel a) {
        setEnabled(true);
        setVisible(true);
        apuesta=a;
        setContentAreaFilled(true);
        setBorderPainted(true);
        setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
        setText(null);

        this.addMouseListener(this);





    }
    public void setMostrarFichas()// Si ficha >0 Se muestra
    {
        setText(""+contador);
        if(contador<=0){
            setOpaque(false);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setBorderPainted(false);
        }else{
            setOpaque(true);
            setContentAreaFilled(true);
            setBorderPainted(true);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            //suma=getIntLabel(suma);  **AQUI ESTARIA EL PROBLEMA**

            if((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK){
                contador++;     

            }else{
                if(contador>0){
                    contador--;}

            }
            suma=suma+contador;
            setMostrarFichas();

            apuesta.setText(""+suma);

    }

    public int getIntLabel(int x)
    {
        if(apuesta.getText() != null){

            x= Integer.parseInt(apuesta.getText());
        }
        return x;

    }
```

El error:

> ```
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
> at Chip.getIntLabel(Chip.java:80)
> at Chip.mouseClicked(Chip.java:59)
> ```

Comment: Qué error te marca? en qué linea exactamente?

Comment: at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Chip.getIntLabel(Chip.java:80)
 at Chip.mouseClicked(Chip.java:59)

Comment: @Frachy que imprime apuesta.getText()?

Comment: El valor anterior que existe en el Jlabel, si es q lo hay

Comment: En lugar de in if trata de meterlo en un try catch para asegurarte que es un numero

Comment: @Sr1871 En que parte?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un pequeño error conceptual aquí; Si uno escribe un condicional como el que tienes:

```
if( apuesta.getText() != null ) {
  x = Integer.parseInt( apuesta.getText() );
}
```

se reflejaria algo redundante, porque el contenido de `apuesta` siempre será distinto de `null`, un `""` es diferente de nulo, entonces siempre va a intentar hacer el parsing a `int`, naturalmente cuando el `JLabel` esté en blanco tomará el 'vacio' y al querer hacer la conversión arrojará la hermosa `NumberFormatException`; Eso efectivamente ocurre la primera vez que el programa ejecuta la instrucción `suma = getIntLabel(suma);`.

Podrías modificar esa condición, por ejemplo, de la forma:

```
if( !apuesta.getText().isEmpty() ) {
  x = Integer.parseInt( apuesta.getText() );
}
```

Ahora con el condicional en este snippet (y sobre todo ***asumiendo*** que `apuesta` siempre contiene lo que la variable `suma` que es del tipo `int` y nada mas) se obtiene que cuando la etiqueta no esté vacía le asigne a `x` la respectiva conversión a entero.

**Edito:**
Lo anterior es basado en la estructura del código fuente que suministraste, lógicamente hay mas maneras de desarrollar una solución totalmente distinta que tal vez ni lleve un condicional para evitar ciertas redundancias (*por ejemplo siempre estar verificando que `apuesta` no esté vacío a sabiendas de que no lo está*), de todas formas siempre es bueno entender los pequeños y básicos detalles.